# Split input text into even chunks using regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I've done everything I can to find the answer to this problem and I'm sure it is simple so forgive me. I have an input string of upper case letters, no spaces, no line feeds, nothing else but letters from A-Z.
I'm trying just to split it into letter pairs using `Regex.Split`. This is what other posts and regex info says it should be

```
string[] letterPairs = Regex.Split(input, ".{0,2}");
```

The string is 40 letters long and I get back a `string[]` with 20 entries. BUT, they are all blank strings "" (not `null` just `string.Empty`).
I'm using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.
Using `Regex.Match` and then looping through the matches works fine but not split.
Any ideas?

Comment: This works without regex - `var output = input.Select((c, i) => new { c, i }).GroupBy(x => x.i / 2).Select(x => String.Join("", x.Select(y => y.c))).ToArray();` - is that good for you?

Comment: From MSDN: _If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array._ So not sure if there is any possible solution with regex.

Comment: What is the output you seek? I think you need either `.{0,2}(.{0,2})` or `.({0,2}).{0,2}`.

Comment: What is the expected output for `ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ` string? Check this [demo](http://ideone.com/Eu3AIL).

Comment: I'm trying to get an array with two and two letter pairs thus: string[] {"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have

```
//              1       10        20        30        40
string input = "ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ";
```

When you use `.{0,2)` regex, you make the regex engine look for 0 to 2 (but as many as possible since the quantifier is greedy) characters other than a newline. So, it finds `AB`, `CD`, etc. and uses these values as delimiters, thus, removing them and keeping empty strings as the resulting array elements.

Now, to force the elements to remain in the array, you can use a *capturing mechanism*: when a pattern is enclosed with `()`, the text captured that way will be output as a resulting array element.

> If capturing parentheses are used in a **[Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx)** expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

However, [docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array. For example, splitting a string on a single hyphen causes the returned array to include an empty string in the position where two adjacent hyphens are found.

and

> If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array.

So, you will need to also get rid of empty elements (it is easy with LINQ).

This is the solution to split just into 2-symbol substrings:

```
var letterPairs = Regex.Split(input, "(.{0,2})").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("["+String.Join(",", letterPairs)+"]");
// => [AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ]
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Eu3AIL)

If you need `[CD,GH,AB,EF,IJ,CD,GH,AB,EF,IJ]` as output, use

```
var letterPairs = Regex.Split(input, ".{0,2}(.{0,2})").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)).ToList();
```

If you need `[AB,EF,IJ,CD,GH,AB,EF,IJ,CD,GH]` as output, use

```
var letterPairs = Regex.Split(input, "(.{0,2}).{0,2}").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex, use something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> SplitByCount(String input, Int32 count)
{
    if (input == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("input"); }
    if (count <= 0) { throw new ArgumentException("Count has to be positive.", "count"); }

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i += count)
    {
        yield return input.Substring(i, Math.Min(count, input.Length - i));
    }
}
```

Which you can then invoke by:

```
var input = "HelloThisIsGoingToBeFunBut";
var result = SplitByCount(input, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to be exactly what we have to expect if we inspect what `Split()` is specified to do: 
The regex string you provide as its second argument specifies the **delimiter**, not the actual elements you want to split. The strings between the delimiter are indeed all empty strings.
If you really want to use regexps for this task, you might try `Match()`. But in this case you might really be better off using a simple for loop.

[MSDN Regexp.Split]
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx